# Best way of converting date string to timestamp?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

It's been a long long day and it's getting close to 2am here.

I was wondering if someone could give me some guidance towards the best solution of converting this string to timestamp and then converting it date time so it can be inserted into a database.

I know there is ways like this:

```
$d = new DateTime('26-10-2018');
$timestamp = $d->getTimestamp(); // Unix timestamp
$formatted_date = $d->format('Y-m-d'); // 2018-26-10
```

But is there anything which accepts the hours and minutes aswell?

```
$datestring = "26-10-2018 09:30";
```

Comment: Why down votes? please explain if you're going to down vote.

Comment: Sleep is a coder's friend, well... anyone's friend really. I'm pretty sure you'd of most likely solved this yourself in the morning when your brain's fresh and nicely rested and nice cup of coffee with a danish to boot ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('26-10-2018 09:30'));`

Comment: That's worked, Thank you! The lack of sleep is getting to me haha

Comment: No thanks, but the date function has a limite, it cannot support more than 2038.